# php curl login issue (blank page)

Tags: php, curl

UPDATE: I am now able to to access the main homepage, but i am not logged in.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.xxx.com/?cmd=home');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'emailAddress=jeffanderson@tradermail.info&persist=on&pswd=qweqwe&from=/?cmd=home');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

echo $content;
```

Comment: You didn't just post your username and password, did you?

Comment: yes but its an account i dont use

Comment: you may need to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` if their login system uses redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Add `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);`.

Answer (score 0):

`curl_exec()` returns false if there was a problem:

```
$content = curl_exec($ch);
if ($content === FALSE) {
      die(curl_error($ch));
}
return($content);
```

Comment: Try doing `curl_setopt($ch, 'CURLOPT_HEADER', true)`, which'll return as well as the body of the request. That should help with debugging.

Comment: @Marc B nothing happened still blank page. If its not too much trouble could you attempt to make a curl script with my login information on swagbucks.com email:jeffanderson@tradermail.info pass:qweqwe

Comment: Hey, are you running that code inside a function, or is that the entirety of the script? If it's NOT inside a function, change the "return" to an "echo" and you should get content.

Comment: @Marc B Got it to work a little. It loads the homepage but i am not logged in. Any ideas why that could be?

Comment: No idea. Probably submitting the user/pass to the wrong spot, or with the wrong field names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things. First, add the following two options to CURL:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
```

That will tell CURL to follow any redirects. Then, change return to echo. Echo will send the data to the browser. Then you are all set!

Answer (score 0):

after all honorable answer..u put all together in below way

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.xxx.com/?cmd=sb-login&from=/?cmd=home');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'emailAddress=xxx@tradermail.info&persist=on&pswd=xxx&from=/?cmd=home');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
if (FALSE===$content  {
      echo "Follwowing error:".curl_error();
      die(curl_errorno($ch));
}
curl_close ($ch);
return($content);
```